# How to get the client IP in DataSnap 2010

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010, datasnap

Someone can tell me how to get the client ip of a connected session from the server side?.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
procedure TMyDSService.DataSnapServerConnect(DSConnectEventObject: TDSConnectEventObject);
var
  Conn: TIdTCPConnection;
begin
   Conn := TIdTCPConnection(DSConnectEventObject.ChannelInfo.Id);
   Trace('Client ' + Conn.Socket.Binding.PeerIP +':' + IntToStr(Conn.Socket.Binding.PeerPort));
   Trace('Client info: ' + DSConnectEventObject.ChannelInfo.Info);
end;
```

Comment: `DSConnectEventObject.ChannelInfo.Info` always return the IP address of server, is this a bug or i`m missing something ?

http://db.tt/lmRoqD2

Answer (score 3):

You query the `Request.RemoteAddr` to get the ip address of the attached client.

Comment: RemoteAddr is a method of TWebRequest, I think it's not accesible in Datasnap.